# regex in `/bin/sh` shell

Tags: shell, wildcards

I would like to remove all files ending with a given set of extensions in a
particular directory in a `/bin/sh` shell. With a `/bin/bash` I can do it with
`regex` like this :

```
rm path/(*.pdf|*.png)
```

but this doesn't seem to work with plain sh. Is it normal ? Is there any
kind of regex `support`?

Comment: Are you really asking about the Bourne shell (which is not found on many systems these days), and not about POSIX shells such as `/bin/sh` on Linux, *BSD, OSX, etc.?

Comment: @Gilles I may be confused... I thought that `/bin/sh` was a Bourne shell. My question refers to `/bin/sh`

Comment: `/bin/sh` was the Bourne shell in commercial unices, but never on Linux or *BSD where it's another shell (usually dash or one of the ksh variants these days) which is mostly compatible with the Bourne shell and POSIX-compliant.

Comment: Note that `(*.pdf|*.png)` is not a regexp. As a (extended) regex, that would rather be something like `^path/[^/]*\.(pdf|png)$`. You can easily see the regexps are not really adapted to do globbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work in a strictly POSIX-compliant shell.  Here's the normative reference:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_03

As you can see, definitely no regex, and not even the {a,b} brace notation.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [user3188445's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223896/52727) this is not POSIX-compliant.

However, if you want to do it anyway, you have to use another tool like `find`:

```
find dir/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*.pdf\|.*.png" -delete
```

`find` searches the dir `dir/`, not recursively (`-maxdepth 1`), only file are found (`-type f`). The regular expression matches .pdf and .png files and `-delete` remove the files found.

Answer (score 1):

To check what shell you are really using with /bin/sh, call:

```
/bin/sh whatshell.sh
```

and fetch the whatshell script from this page:

http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/

call e.g. `wget http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/whatshell/whatshell.sh`

Typical output:

```
$ sh whatshell.sh
SVR4 Bourne shell (SunOS 5 variant)

$ bosh whatshell.sh
SVR4 Bourne shell (SunOS 5 schily variant)

$ bash whatshell.sh
bash 3.2.25(1)-release

$ ksh whatshell.sh 
ksh88 Version (..-)11/16/88i

$ ksh93 whatshell.sh
ksh93 Version M 1993-12-28 s+
```

POSIX does not require a POSIX shell in /bin/sh. If you like to 
run a POSIX shell call:

```
PATH=`getconf PATH` export PATH
sh
```

note that if this resuls in running bash, the shell is not expected to 
be POSIX compliant.

Comment: What do you mean by _is not expected to be POSIX compliant_? `bash` aims at POSIX compliance when called as `sh`. It's even certified on OS/X (where it's built with a stricter compliance mode).

Comment: POSIX certified unfortunately does not mean POSIX compliant. The problem with Mac OS X seems to be that the POSIX validation scripts do not check everything and thus let bash slip though... bash3.x is not POSIX compliant at all, bash4.x is much better but still has minor problems, I unfortunatly forgot what exactly. The main problem with bash3 is that it does not exit on errors with bash -ce 'cmd' and that it runs commands from bash -ce 'cmd' under job control and thus in a different process group.

Comment: BTW: a warning on bash including bash4: rm [A-Z]* will remove all files that start with a letter and not only those with upper case letters. The Bourne Shell, ksh-88 ksh93 and zsh do this as expected.

Comment: All shells have POSIX compliance bugs. They are found and fixed as they're found. `dash`, `mksh`, `yash`, `ksh93`, `bash` the current Free Software POSIX shells are no different in that regard. If you want one case where `bash` is compliant  and most others are not, try for instance: `"$shell" -c 'IFS=£; echo "$*"' sh a b` in a UTF-8 locale (only `yash` and `bash` compliance there).

Comment: About [A-Z] That would be in non-POSIX locales, where the behaviour is unspecified. `bash`'s behaviour is allowed by POSIX there.

Comment: Also note that `[A-Z]` fails to match É in a French locale in mksh, zsh, dash or schily-sh.

Comment: I know that [A-Z] does not include Ö, but it ruined me part of a Linux installation when I used this rm command before I compiled my preferred shells.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `zsh` did the same as `bash` or `yash` in `"$shell" -c 'IFS=£; echo "$*"' sh a b`.